# Username authentication in WCF service not working

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

So I'm pretty new to WCF and I need a basic username or certificate based authentication scheme for some basic security to only allow the service to be used from my application. Anyways, to keep things short this is my configuration so

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
    contract="uConnect.Web.IUConnectService" name="wsHttpBindingEndpoint" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=tempCert" storeLocation="CurrentUser" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="uConnect.Web.AuthValidation, uConnect.Web" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here is my custom validation class with a hard-coded username/password combination approach for now

```
namespace uConnect.Web
{
class AuthValidation : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName != "test" || password != "test")
            throw new SecurityException("Error: username/password combination invalid.");
    }
}
}
```

I've followed several tutorials and I believe everything is configured correctly. However the problem isn't that the service doesn't work, it works fine. The problem is that I can access my service contract and call methods without ever providing a username/password. However, if I decorate my class with the attribute `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]` then it will crash when I try to access it. Now this may be because I'm not actually authenticated, or something else entirely. But all exception thrown isn't the `SecurityException` that I'm expecting.

One last thing, all the tutorials I've seen so far show that you provide the username/password such as

```
myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "p@ssw0rd";
```

But when I add the WCF contract reference to my solution it's provided as a class of type `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` which doesn't offer the property `ClientCredentials`. Any ideas on how I should proceed and get a simple authentication scheme working?

Answer (score 0):

This may be late to post but I had the same problem, turns out My validator class logic wasn't doing pretty well job. Here's my solution

```
 public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (!(userName == "test1" && password == "1tset") && !(userName == "test2" && password == "2tset"))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
```